# Kotlin collections: 'break out' early on null / empty / blank

Tags: kotlin, collections, functional-programming

I have a list of data class items as a kind of lookup table, thereby searching for a NAME and returning the corresponding ID:

```
data class Test(
  var ID: String,
  var NAME: String
)

val lookupList = listOf(
  Test(ID ="0B82B4DEB07046B28BE6B861B6851DAD", NAME = "Alpha"),
  Test(ID ="1F72F6C6AAB94F94B18A3AD661A2907E", NAME = "Beta"),
  Test(ID ="4C23246F49EB40BB9D71FB9D0FBE25C0", NAME = "Gamma"),
  Test(ID ="5D5F022A29934C77AE48E7FCFB0B985F", NAME = "Delta")
)

val testName = "Gamma"

val resultID = lookupList
  .filter { it.NAME == testName }
  .map { it.ID }                             // will fail when testName = ""
  .first()

println(resultID)   // prints "4C23246F49EB40BB9D71FB9D0FBE25C0"
```

Now in some cases *testName* can be empty. In that case the application will crash on **.map { it.ID }** as the filtered list will be empty.

In such a case *resultID* should get to be assigned *null*. The best I can come up with is to add a Test() entry for NAME = "" to the lookup list:

```
data class Test(var ID: String, var NAME: String)

val lookupList = listOf(
  Test(ID ="0B82B4DEB07046B28BE6B861B6851DAD", NAME = "Alpha"),
  Test(ID ="1F72F6C6AAB94F94B18A3AD661A2907E", NAME = "Beta"),
  Test(ID ="4C23246F49EB40BB9D71FB9D0FBE25C0", NAME = "Gamma"),
  Test(ID ="5D5F022A29934C77AE48E7FCFB0B985F", NAME = "Delta")
)

val testName = ""

val resultID = lookupList
  .union(listOf(Test(ID = "", NAME = "")))   // add case for empty NAME
  .filter { it.NAME == testName }
  .map { it.ID }
  .first().ifBlank { null }                  // return null for empty NAME

println(resultID)
```

Is there a better solution? Is there a way to 'return early' with *null* from within the chain? I tried with ifEmpty() but to no avail.

One remark: *testName* will always be one of the NAME values in *lookupList* or the empty string, never a non-empty string which is not in *lookupList*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's the call to `map` that's failing, but rather the call to `first`. Try using `firstOrNull` instead.

```
val resultID = lookupList
  .filter { it.NAME == testName }
  .map { it.ID }
  .firstOrNull()
```

Comment: The error message even says it: 
List is empty.
at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first